# Mysql error 1267 in batch-file

Tags: mysql, collation, batch-processing

I have a batch like this:

```
mysql.exe -h -u -p data_base < D:\data_base.dat
```

In this data_base.bat i have a query. This query creates a table, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(
select * 
from a 
where a.1 = 'Á'
);
```

i have  windows server 2008 r2 and mysql server 5.6
All database and tables are in latin1_swedish_ci.

When i run de .bat i get the error:

**ERROR 1267 llegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci.IMPLICIT) and (cp850_general_ci, COERCIBLE) for operation '='**

When I remove  '´' in my query, it works fine.

In my opinion, it was a conflict between latin1_swedish_ci in my MySQL server and cp850_general_ci in Windows. Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: \*Slaps head\* -- why, oh why, is MySQL still doing swedish collation by default...

Comment: This question is NOT related to a Windows/DOS Batch .bat file. I have changed the batch-file tag to the appropriate one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think you've already identified the issue. When you created the batch file it got encoded with the default character encoding (and its collation) for your OS. Try using `Notepad++` or any similar utility that let's you re-encode to a different character encoding.

For Notepad++ go to

```
Encoding > Character sets > Western European > Windows-1252
```

Comment: When i change to **Windows-1252**, return same error. I try others Encoding, but the error persisted.

Comment: Glad you've solved the problem. Like I'd said, you had already figured it out! I gave [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) as a suggestion because that's the usual encoding for Latin characters. But, I guess "swedish_ci" or maybe in the context of collation or how MySQL works with them is different.

Comment: Tks @Ravi!! I tried different encoding. I did this: changed the .bat to .sql, and changed encoding to **OEM 850**. Now works great! Tks one more time.

Comment: Yes, I know 1252 didn't work for you. I had seen your comment that ISO-8859-1 worked. In my previous comment I just wanted to share why I had suggested 1252. (For Latin characters that was one the best guess.)

Comment: I thought it was neat, but did not.

Comment: I seem to have a similar problem with a stored procedure (created by running batch files to load a set of .sql files).  It's a string literal being given this same problematic collation type.  Of course, I'm confused where I'd change character set.  Last I knew, only the BOM (Byte Order Mark) gave any clue about what's in an ascii text file (I have no BOM on these files).  I also don't have any characters in the literal more special than `'%'`.